# Light switch wiring [UK]

Tags: switch, light, uk

In my house I have a series of single and double switches Like the one in this picture
[image: Single switch]
[image: Single switch]

I would like to change them to smart switches because of the light bulbs I have installed. Now when I look at the options (like the Aqara), They have options with Neutral wire and without.
[image: Aqara Switches]

Seeing my current installation it seems that it doesn't use neutral, am I right? If so, what's the black cable?

Thanks

Comment: It _appears_ that there are 2 cables (white sheath containing a red/black/ground) entering this box, yet I can only see one black and one ground (covered with a green/yellow sleeve) in your picture. I'm sure the other black and other ground are there _somewhere_. Can you rearrange the wires so that all 6 individual wires are visible and take another pic? It would be helpful to know what the other wires are connected to.

Comment: Hi @FreeMan, The ground cable is in both white sheaths. there's just a green/yellow sleve after it. joining both ground cables.

Comment: Ah! I figured there was a ground from both cables, I just didn't realize and couldn't see that they were both in the same sleeve. On this side of the pond, we just let the bare ground wire continue to run bare in the box, which can make it more obvious that there are two wires. Also, I couldn't see that both blacks ran into the white connector until the 2nd pic. Very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since red is usually live and black is usually neutral (with sufficiently old wires) and since you have two cables with red switched and the black wires connected .... it is reasonably safe to assume that one cable is power, the other goes to the light, that the blacks are in fact neutral.  You can connect the blacks using the existing terminal block to the neutral terminal on the new switch.   You should confirm all this with a meter and you will need to determine, also with a meter, which of the two reds is live power and which goes to the light.  It doesn't matter with the old switch but it does with the new one.

You can eliminate that neutral terminal block if the new switch's neutral terminal can accommodate two wires, and its documentation says that's ok.